# Laravel Application Shows Blank Screen

Tags: apache, laravel-5, amazon-ec2

I finish setting up my laravel application on apache server in amazon ec2, but the application is showing a blank white screen after fixing all the permission issues.

Comment: please include your routes configuration and the error you get? is it some middleware failing, is it some redirection issue? Is it some php error? There can be multiple reasons

Comment: I checked my log files and it doesn't show any error

Comment: Thanks, I’ve fixed it. I had to re upload the application to the server

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that the DocumentRoot of your VirtualHost is pointing to "*yourlaravelproject*/public" folder